# Single Spring Boot application workings for multiple users

Tags: spring-boot, singleton

I wanted to know how a single spring boot application that is being hosted by a server handles different users or different call.

1. Is a new instance of the application created with all new variables and classes for each and every calls.
2. Will the same variables/objects that is being used for one call, be used for other calls. If so, won't we have objects being manipulated by different calls to applications that are independent of each other and won't that give us wrong results.
3. Also, I want to create a global object like static singleton. Will that cause any issues keeping in mind the above points. If yes, what are the alternatives.

Also If you can provide some links to get to know how a single SpringBoot applications (being hosted by a single server) handles different users(Point 1).

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

> Is a new instance of the application created with all new variables and classes for each and every calls.

Nope.

A single app running as a Java process is used to serve all the requests. *At the same time*, beans in Spring have scopes. Some of the beans are request-scoped, for example, and will be re-created for each request. Others may be tied to a specific user session, or even use a custom scope mechanism.

> Will the same variables/objects that is being used for one call, be used for other calls. If so, won't we have objects being manipulated by different calls to applications that are independent of each other and won't that give us wrong results.

They will; we will, if we don't put safeguards in place. If your bean is not stateless, the solution is usually to make sure it has the correct scope or use appropriate synchronization mechanisms.

> Also, I want to create a global object like static singleton. Will that cause any issues keeping in mind the above points. If yes, what are the alternatives.

You don't need static singletons. Spring beans *are* singletons by default. And yes, it might cause issues. Simply put, Spring beans are not automagically thread-safe.